# What aws services can I use in my architecture to apply high availability and tolerant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Im starting to learn about amazon web services, and Im trying to develop a simple application to start to learn better the concepts.

The application architecture at this moment consists in a client that sends a text file, a mapper file and a reducer file to s3, and also sends a message to sqs indicating that client is asking for that files to processing. Then I have a elastic mapreduce cluster, where an ec2 instance starts and get the messages from sqs, get the files from s3, process the files and then store the result processing file in s3. After this processing is sent a notification, using sns to user saying that the result file is available in s3.

Now I would like to use more services in this application to have a tolerant and high availability architecture so I can understand better this two concepts.

**But my doubts at this moment are**: in this simple aplication what service can I use so the app can be tolerant? And what service can I use so the app can have high availabilty?

Im reading about elastic load balancing, having more than one availability zone and if an ec2 stops working in a specific availabilty zone its not a problem because we have the elb with other availability zone.

But in my aplication example I dont have always a server/ec2 instance running, it just starts running when the client sends files for processing and only at this moment the elastic mapreduce cluster starts an ec2 instance to process the files.

**So my doubt is**, if in my basic application scenario I can implement tolerant and high availabilty, and if yes, which would be a good way/services to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would use the new Lambda service, to put the message into the SQS queue, because it makes your application even more robust. If you do this, then your client which uploads the tasks to S3 needs to be able to handle only S3. Then Lambda gets triggered by S3 that it has new files and puts the message into SQS.

S3, SQS is HA and fault tolerant. Using these services makes your application robust ( but you need to take care about the all the components).

Since your jobs are in SQS until the jobs are done, in the event of a failure of the job execution, after a time limit the job gets active again and an other executer will start to work on it. This makes your EMR jobs also Fault tolerant.

In the event of a trouble with an entire Availability zone, your entire EMR stack will be down. After a certain time your failed jobs will be getting online agin. So if you have 2 clusters in 2 separate AZ feeding by the same SQS, you can tolerate an entire AZ failure.
[EMR and AZ-s](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#regions-and-availability-zones)

If you need even higher robustness, like handling a Region problem, you can do that too, but that's a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im with a doubt, I have the messages in sqs, but when the elastic mapreduce cluster starts an ec2 instance to process the files, this instance will read the sqs messages and then that messages are deleted. So if the elastic mapreduce ec2 instance read the messages from sqs, starts to do the mapreduce job but for some reason stops the mapreduce job will not work. And my doubt is how to solve this cases?

Comment: May help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_54Jcmi4zM

http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/speed-and-reliability-at-any-scale-amazon-sqs-and-database-services-svc206-aws-reinvent-2013-28430970

Comment: If you retrieve a message from SQS it's not getting deleted. You need to send back a message to the SQS that the process of that message was successful. However I never used it with EMR, but I would surprise if it wouldn't support this feature and deletes the message immediately. But do a test. Put a job into a queue which would run for long. Then delete the EMR instance during execution of the job. ( Set the  visibility timeout for just 1-2 minutes.) You should see the job running again soon. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you said and I get this, Cluster:  Terminated with errors The master node was terminated by user.

Comment: I still believe that the jobs are staying in the queue in an invisible state until the EMR process is not done.